# Having an imageview inside a navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a project where there is a navigation drawer.In the navigation drawer , i want to place an imageview above a listivew.The xml layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
         >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#CC000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#808080"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_view"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The issue is that the imageview appears squished/compressed on running on a device.Why does it appear to be compressed?Please help!!

Comment: Post a picture of how it looks on device, so that we can understand more clearly the issue.

Comment: Your `Imageview`'s height is `wrap_content` and you didn't specify that on which device you'r running your app. This problem is because of different screen resolution. In big device image will be squished. So you need to apply some fixed height to your `ImageView`.

Comment: specify the height of image view or use the compressed image and fixed the height and width of image as you desire

Comment: @PiyushGupta .So can i hard code a height value in dp?The icon resoulution is as follows hdpi:161x48px,mdpi:107x32px,xhdpi:214x63px,xxhdpi:321x95px, how do i set a value compatible with all ,or do i have to do different layouts in layout folders?

Comment: For different screen resolution you just put your image in different `drawable` folder which will be accessed with different folder for different screen device. So don't worry about that. Just apply fixed height to imageview.

Comment: @PiyushGupta What height can you suggest which would be common for all the above resolutions?

Comment: @AchuthanM Between 150 to 200 or you can use weight property too

Comment: @PiyushGupta, it is the height which is giving the problem.Are you sure you are talking about the height(150 to 200)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:
you have the imageView width set to "match_parent" and height set to "wrap_content" which is going to cause the image to stretch horizontally unless it is the same width as the device - set the width to "wrap_content" and center the image if necessary.

also...

Relative layouts don't have orientation so you should remove the line -

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: I am setting the width of the image to match_parent because it would match the width of the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute in your imageview:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Also, use the src attribute for the drawable, not the background attribute:

```
android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
```